# mysqli_query insert with localhost, table not updating

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am trying to insert user details into a table i have created using phpmyadmin on a local host server.

the connections are fine and the first user gets inserted into the table no problem.

when I attempt to add another user it does not show in the table in phpmyadmin nor do i get any kind of error.

I have a feeling its something to do with the table configuration but i cannot find any info on this, can something please help.

**The Insert code**

```
$result = db_query("INSERT INTO registration_list (first_name, last_name, student_number, email, activation_code, status, time_created, time_updated)
    VALUES (
            '$fname',
            '$sname',
            '$studentNo',
            '$email',
            '$code',
            'awaiting approval',
            now(),
            now()
        )");
```

**The connection**

```
function db_connect(){

static $connection;

if(!isset($connection)) {
    $connection = connectLocalHost($connection);
}
if($connection === false) {
    return db_error();
}
return $connection;
}

function db_query($query) {
// Connect to the database
$connection = db_connect();
// Query the database
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: Did you got any error? Try to print `print_r(  mysqli_error($connection) )` if it show anyone...

Comment: Give a try on `print_r(mysqli_error($connection))` after `mysqli_query();`